# GKGoal toAvoid is being ignored

Tags: swift, gamekit

Hello and thank you for taking the time to help.

I am experimenting with GKGoals and have been able to understand and make them all work except for toAvoid.

In the code below the toSeek is working fine, but the toAvoid is ignored / overruled by the to seek completely - the 'player' just walking right through the obstacles. Even though I have weighted the toAvoid strongly.

What am I doing wrong, or what do I not understand please. Many thanks

```
EXTRACT
let obstacles = [GKCircleObstacle(radius: 100), GKCircleObstacle(radius: 100), GKCircleObstacle(radius: 100), GKCircleObstacle(radius: 100)]
obstacles[0].position = vector_float2(200, 500)
obstacles[1].position = vector_float2(250, 500)
obstacles[2].position = vector_float2(300, 500)
obstacles[3].position = vector_float2(20, 500)



EXTRACT
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, 
with event: UIEvent?) {
for t in touches {
loc = t.location(in: self)
print("touchesBegan \(loc)")
}

let targetMove = float2(loc!)
let newTarget = GKAgent2D()
newTarget.position = targetMove

let mmg: [MoveC] = 
entityManager.moveComponentsForTeam(.team1)
let goal1 = GKGoal(toSeekAgent: newTarget)
let goal2 = GKGoal(toAvoid: obstacles, maxPredictionTime: 2)
mmg[0].behavior?.setWeight(10, for: goal1)
mmg[0].behavior?.setWeight(1000, for: goal2)
mmg[0].behavior = GKBehavior(goals: [goal1,goal2])

}
```

Comment: Just a thought, in the above I have created an array of obstacles, and then set their position. Is that all? Do I need to ADD them - I have read the documentation and cannot see that I do.

Comment: ALSO - perhaps it is a grid reference point - is the grid reference for the GKObstacle the same as for the GKScene. or is 0,0 origin different